# Why can't I install anything? No error given, just endlessly "tries"

Tags: applications, google-play-store, installation, downloading

I have been unable to install anything on my Moto E5 Play (Android 8.0). It never gives an error, or any indication that something's wrong, it just eternally spins the loading circle around the app's icon and says "waiting for download." It'll go on for DAYS if I wait that long to press cancel.

I really don't think it's a data usage issue, as it just reset 3 days ago. I also don't think it's a storage issue, as I have 6+ GB free (16 total) and have not been getting any error messages that seem to go along with other questions that end up being storage related.

Things I have tried:

-rebooting (twice)

-installing ~5 other apps, including ones I've never had

-UNinstalling an app, and trying to reinstall it (can't)

-clearing cache for Google Play and Google Play Services

-turning data saver on and off again

-turning data saver on and telling it to let Google Play and Google Play Services have unrestricted data access

-killing and restarting Google Play at nearly every step

---

I'm probably rambling on this last bit, but I also have the tendency to leave out things that end up being important, so...

I have this vague notion that maybe, somehow, it has too many apps trying to install. My old phone broke a few months ago, and when I got this one, I found that any app I could remember having, was already endlessly trying to install. However, then, I could cancel and tell it to install again right away, and it would work.

Answer (score 0):

It's been happening again lately, but 2 or 3 times now it's resolved itself when I cancelled another forever-pending update I never requested. I get the feeling it's like 2 or more updates are stuck in the door, and neither wants to let the other go first.

Whatever's going on, and in lieu of another, better answer, try this - go to Google Play, tap for the menu (the "hamburger" in the search field) and click "My apps & games." X off updates till one starts making some progress.